# Implementing Sub menu/category with material design lite

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design

I am developing a map website with openlayers and im trying to design it with material design lite. I want it to have some sort of a checkbox group that if you check something it highlights it on the map, the checkboxes should show only after clicking a category. I have a layout that when you click the menu the categories open, and i want the checkboxes to be hidden and only apear for each category after i click it. I want the checkboxes to be inside the layout menu like a sub-menu for each category. So the problem is i cant quite figure out what mdl tags/classes to use for such a sub-menu for the nav categories in the layout menu. Does anybody know a way of creating such a menu with mdl tags or combining regular html tags with mdl?

Thanks for your help, Eyal.